# Use "convert to auto property" on multiple properties at once

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, refactoring, resharper

I find myself using Resharper's "convert to auto property" refactoring a lot to remove pre C# 3.0 boilerplate code.

Is there a way I can apply this to **all properties in a single class** at once?

Comment: Warning:  anything that relies on fields (such as `BinaryFormatter`) could be impacted by this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ReSharper can do this:

```
Options -> Code Cleanup -> Use auto-property, if possible
```

Run code cleanup for the class - and you should be done.

Answer (score 3):

Tanascius has the right answer, though you can tweak that a little bit by creating your own custom Code Cleanup script that would ONLY include the "Use auto-property if possible" refactoring.

That would probably be preferable if you didn't want the rest of the refactorings to run. Just hit the add button on the code cleanup and then uncheck everything else.

-Max