# Converting Regular Properties to Auto-Implemented Properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm upgrading an old C# code-base and would like to convert the regular properties to auto-implemented properties. Can this be done from Visual Studio?

Comment: Warning: If you are using `BinaryFormatter` to serialize things this will break your serialization code.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky no, very much not. Automatically implemented properties get very different field names; `BinaryFormatter` is a field-based serializer and the **field names matter**. So if you serialize your data from `private int foo; public int Foo {get {return foo;} set {foo = value; } }` and then try to deserialize with `public int Foo {get;set;}` it will go "boom".

Comment: @Marc - Oops, sorry. Good point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is [possible using Resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915073/use-convert-to-auto-property-on-multiple-properties-at-once). You could download a fully [functioning trial version for 30 days](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Comment: Thanks. I was about to try CodeRush. I will check Resharper as well.

Comment: meh; every time I install it I conclude I don't get much from it and uninstall it again...

Comment: @Marc - The main benefit I get from it is refactoring, like in this case. I'll remove that bit since it's subjective.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a built in method to do this in VS, but you can use tools like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to do this sort of refactoring.